# Android Service start

Tags: android, service

i created `Service` to download movies and notificate progress, and i found a problem when i start downloading and then exit from app my Service create new without destroying the previous one.

**Log :**

```
 CREATE  // I press Download button Service Created
 START  
 RUN
 CREATE  // I exit from app and it creates new, without DESTROY
 START
 RUN    
 START   // I press to stop downloading
 DESTROY
```

**DownloadManager.java**

```
public class DownloadManager extends Service{



private ExecutorService exec;

private int mb = 1024*1024;
private int Notifid;
private int progressPercent;

private String title;
private String url;

private boolean serviceWork = true;

private NotificationManager manager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();   
    exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    manager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    url = intent.getStringExtra(C.SERVICE_URL);
    title = intent.getStringExtra(C.SERVICE_TITLE);

    if(url.equals("cancel")){
     stopSelf();
    }       
    else {          
        Run run = new Run(url, title);
        serviceWork = true;
        exec.execute(run);
    }

    Notifid = 0x45;

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(url.equals("cancel")){
        cancel();
    }           
    serviceWork = false;
    super.onDestroy();
}


void generateNotify(String msg1, String msg2){              
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    builder.setContentTitle(msg1);
    builder.setContentText(msg2);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher, 0);
    builder.setTicker(msg1);
    builder.setProgress(0, 0, true);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadManager.class);
    intent.putExtra(C.SERVICE_URL, "cancel");
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(pending);
    manager.notify(Notifid, builder.build());   

}

void progress(final int progress, final String msg){
    new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    builder.setProgress(100, progress, false);
                    builder.setContentText(msg);
                    manager.notify(Notifid, builder.build());   
                }
         }
    ).start();
}

void ticker(String msg1){
    builder.setTicker(msg1);
    builder.setContentText(msg1);
    manager.notify(Notifid, builder.build());   
}

void cancel(){
    manager.cancel(Notifid);
}

void cancable(){
    builder.setOngoing(false);

    Intent intent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("sdcard/Mover/"+title+".mp4"), "video/*");

    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(pending);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    manager.notify(Notifid, builder.build());
}

class Run implements Runnable{

    private String url;
    private String title;

    private int count;
    private int fileLength;

    public Run(String url, String title) {
        this.url = url;
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{

            // Создаем подключение к ссылке.

            URL openUrl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection connection = openUrl.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // Проверяем наличие папки если отсуствует создаем.

            File file = new File("sdcard/Mover/");
            file.mkdirs();

            // Размер файла

            fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // Загружаем конетнт

            InputStream ips = new BufferedInputStream(openUrl.openStream());
            OutputStream ops = new FileOutputStream("sdcard/Mover/"+title+".mp4");

            // Показываем уведомление
            DownloadManager.this.generateNotify(title, "Всего: " +format(fileLength));

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int total = 0;
            int last = 0;
            int progress = 1;
            int lasttotal = 0;

            int speed = 0;

            long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // Читаем
            while ((count = ips.read(data)) != -1) {
                if(serviceWork){
                    ops.write(data, 0, count);                  
                    total += count;    

                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    // Определяем скорость загрзки. 
                    // Для этого делаем  проверку на каждую секунду
                    if(now > current + 1000){
                        current = now;

                        speed = (total - lasttotal)/1024;                       
                        lasttotal = total;
                    }


                    progressPercent = (total*100)/fileLength;
                    if(last != progressPercent){
                        last = progressPercent;
                        progress++;
                        DownloadManager.this.progress(progress, "Всего: " +format(fileLength) + " / " + format(total) + " / " + speed + "KB/s");                            
                    }
                }
            }

            ops.flush();
            // Закрываем 

            ops.close();
            ips.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finish();           
    }

    void finish(){
        DownloadManager.this.ticker("Загрузка успешно завершена.");
        DownloadManager.this.stopSelf();
        DownloadManager.this.cancable();
    }

    void stop(){
        DownloadManager.this.stopSelf();
        DownloadManager.this.cancel();
    }

}


public String format(int m){

    String size = m%mb+"";
    size = size.substring(0, Math.min(size.length(), 2));

    return m/mb + "." + size + "мб";
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inspecting the return flag specified in your `onStartCommand` I can see you have specified `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`. The Javadoc for this type of return flag states;

> if this service's process is killed while it is started (after
>   returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then it will be
>   scheduled for a restart and the last delivered Intent re-delivered to
>   it again via onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)

From this explanation it is apparent that your service is being killed. The reason for this is unclear but ensuring Services (and their child threads) remain 'alive' is something I have grappled with before. In our application we found that phone sleeps were particularly destructive. We 'hacked' (?) around these nuances by giving the service a Wake-Lock and WiFi-Lock to ensure (a) the Service wasn't mothballed on sleep and (b) the system kept a wifi lock (i.e. didn't drop the active wifi connection) whilst we had work to do in our child threads. Please look into your Service's behaviour under a sleep environment after we get this sorted. 
Nonetheless, this flag seems to explain the apparent restarting of your service and the download re-attempt.

From briefly reviewing your code I see that you are communicating with your service from your thread. An `IntentService` maybe applicable in this scenario as Ranjith points out. However, the child thread cannot communicate with the Service which spun off the worker thread. The reason for this is that the hosting service is almost immediately killed after spinning off the worker thread since the service's job is done with all remaining work being completed asynchronously. This could explain why this didn't work for you.

To move forward with this I would attempt one of the following;

1. Use an `IntentService` and move all notification code down into the thread and sever all AsyncTask-Service communications. Please also note the comments I made regarding WakeLocks and WiFiLocks for network comms. These tools appear quite dangerous for the Battery if used without care.
2. If you want your service to exist as long as your child thread then I would suggest returning  the `START_STICKY` flag from your service and allowing your app to bind to it (ref: [Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) to see how it's getting on.

Answer (score 2):

I can sugget you using IntentService. Where android take cares of your worker thread logic.just little porting work need. You can find the code below

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics

Comment: Can i know the problem when using IntentService

Comment: Are you calling the Service by context.startService(service); i am just putting your code to eclipse please wait

Comment: Your code has error can you upload a non error code.. Constants error fine

Comment: Can you put the finish in finally block